# Preview Report Crashes Access

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a report in Microsoft Access 97 (yes, I know) that works properly on my client's copy of Server 2003. However, when I try to run it on my own copy of Server 2003, the report crashes Access immediately. It does the same in Server 2008 R2 and Server 2012 R2. Now, the interesting thing is that the query underneath that report runs perfectly, which I would think rules out things like MDAC. There's nothing unusual about the report -- no strange fonts or graphics -- at least nothing obvious. If I can get it working in an environment identical to the client's, then I can move it forward to other operating systems. Where should I start looking for the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of crash is related to missing references..You need to go to the VBA Editor (ALT + F11) -> Tools -> References and check if you have any **MISSING**

Comment: Good idea, but none of the references are marked as missing.

Comment: Recently i encountered another strange case that resulted in nasty crashes....ocx/dll with different versions ...if my memory serves me right was mscomctl.ocx ..maybe this the problem...see if you have identical versions on both machines

Comment: First, thanks for your help. I've had trouble with mscomctl in the past. A Microsoft patch uninstalled it from the system, forcing me to manually replace it. Come Monday morning, I'll remote into this particular client and see what version of it they're running.

Answer (score 0):

Import everything from your current project into a new blank project, seems like that is the only resolution I have been able to find online.

The information that I found can be viewed here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/access-97-crashes-opening-a-report.3901588/

Comment: Doubt very much that the database file is corrupt, as I copied the actual mdb file from the client (who is currently using that same file successfully) to my development machine. But in any case, I saved the report into a new mdb file and also imported the report into a different new mdb. In both cases, attempting to preview the copied report crashed Access.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, don't ask me why:

I found the printing worked and so did Layout View

- Open the report in Layout View
- Save the report

It works!